# addEventListener doesn't work in an event listener

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I have an event listener, which listen to document load (this is "myExtension" and it's work correctly). And I want to put another listener into this listener, but it doesn't work. This is that listener:

```
 myExtension.$("#quicklink img").addEventListener("click", function(){ alert("It's works!"); }, false, true);
```

but if I change that listener to this listener:

```
 document.addEventListener("click", function(){ alert("It's works!"); }, false, true);
```

it works correctly.

`$("#quicklink img")` - it's an array with images, there are some of them in the page (0-20 ea).

I want to use this, only some pages, so I need myExtension, because I don't want to work all sites, where there are img in an element with quicklink id.

Why it doesn't work? What is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

> $("#quicklink img") - it's an array with images, there are some of them in the page (0-20 ea).

Arrays don't have an `addEventListener` method. You would have to loop over it and call `addEventListener` on each HTMLElementNode.

Comment: ok, but when I tried this: myExtension.$("#quicklink img:eq(0)").addEventListener("click", function(){ alert("It's works!"); }, false, true); this doesn't work too, and this is only one element.

Comment: @golddragon007 — Presumably, based on your previous statements, your call to `$` will return an array with one item in it. An array containing one thing is not the thing itself and you still need to loop over it.

Comment: this is $("#quicklink img") return only that images which I need

Comment: but if I use this: myExtension.getElementById('a1').addEventListener("click", function(){ alert("It's works!"); }, false, true); where "a1" is only one image's id, it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the listener on each image

```
$("#quicklink img").each( function(){
  $(this).click(function(){
    alert("It's work");
  });
});
```

Comment: The question says that `$("#quicklink img")` returns an array, which implies it isn't jQuery so it won't have an `each` method.

Answer (score 0):

I find my answer

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() { myExtension.init(); }, false);
var myExtension = {
 $: jQuery.noConflict(true),

 init: function() {
  gBrowser.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", myExtension.onPageLoad, true);
 },

onPageLoad: function(aEvent) {
 [...]
 var wnd = aEvent.target.defaultView;
 wnd.document.getElementById('a1').addEventListener("click", function(){ alert("It's works!"); }, false, true);
 [...]
}
```

where "a1" is one image id